# Java Struts tag iterator struggling over large list

Tags: java, struts2, tags, iterator, struts

Just a general question here.
I have a simple web app which allows the user(s) to filter through a number of records in a database. Now this isn't a particularly large list (1,200 - 1,500 at the moment)

But I seem to be having something of a sporadic issue with no errors and was wondering if anyone had seem something similar.

Basically my returned List is returning the expected number of results (example 1,267) but *sometimes* not all of the results are being displayed. Sometimes you run the search and you get all 1,267, another time the page seems to just 'stall' at say 74 or 123 or something. Hit search again and the same might happen, hit it again and this time it works (all 1,267 returned). Then it'll work for the next 2 or 3 times, then it'll go back to only displaying say 73 results again.

Now from a Java point of view the List is correct, so this has to be an issue with Struts tags (specifically `<s:iterator>`).

I was just wondering if anyone else had experienced this and how to get around it.

Also on the note of this, the results do seem to load back VERY slowly, almost like blocks of 10, then a 2 second delay then another 10, so as you can imagine 1,267 would take about a minute! Which seems very wrong.

As you can see, there's nothing special in the iterator:

```
 <s:iterator value="resultList" var="obj" status="row">
    <tr>
        <td>[<s:property value="%{#row.count}"/>]</td>
        <td noWrap="true"align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="allocateChkBox" value="<s:property value="#obj.id"/>" /></td>      
        <td noWrap="true"><s:property value="#obj.reference"/></td>
        <td noWrap="true"><s:property value="#obj.status"/></td>
        <td noWrap="true"><s:property value="#obj.resource"/></td>
        <td noWrap="true"><s:property value="#obj.society"/></td>
        <td noWrap="true" align="center"><s:property value="#obj.date"/></td>
        <td noWrap="true" align="center"><s:textfield size="11" name="quantity" value="%{#obj.quantity}"/></td>                 
        <td noWrap="true"><s:property value="#obj.embellisher"/></td>
        <td noWrap="true" align="center"><s:textfield  maxLength="5" size="2" name="boxNumber" value="%{#obj.boxNumber}" /></td>
        <td noWrap="true" align="center"><s:textfield size="11" name="trackingNumber" value="%{#obj.trackingNumber}"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: it depends on how the search button works, so better post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Are you telling us that you actually show 1500 rows in a web page ? This is clearly an antipattern... can't you use pagination ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar slowness when the list contains more records. The reason is because the iterator results in log of "out.write" statements in the final jsp class.

In your case, each iteration has close to 10 out.write for  and this is concatenated with  &  on both sides.

One way of improving the performance drastically is by forming the table content on server side using a StringBuilder and writing the final string using  tag (replacing the iterator).